# Can we get all the journey details using API or SSJS or Ampsctipt on a cloud page

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud, ssjs, ampscript

I wanted to created a cloud page that takes journey link as input both activated and draft journeys and produce the list of configured emails and their subjects lines sender and delivery profiles and journey settings.

Tried with ampscript it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a "journey link"?  What you're describing is covered by multiple REST APIs.  Is there one in particular that's tripping you up?

Comment: THANKS  for the response Adam. Journey link in the sence link of individual journey url , Thanks for confirming scenarios will covered by REST API , the thing is tipping me is instead of API  is it possible just by using ampsctipt and ssjs , I know those are limited can we get close to APIs with Ampsctipt and SSJS